# info.plist permission to show application in setting

Tags: ios, swift, settings, info.plist

My application does not show in setting. this is my info.plist [image]

what params should I add to appear app in setting?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite common for a new app to be shown in the Settings App, I have faced it earlier. It is an apple bug, but there is no definite way to solve the issue. Like for someone, it is told restarting the device solved the problem, other says logout from apple id and re-login solved the issue. You may follow the [thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/274921/why-are-my-app-settings-not-appearing-in-the-settings-app).